gorm define a valid foreign key for relations
I have following tables in postgresql:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "offices" (
    "id"              uuid        NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
    "full_name"       text        NOT NULL,
    "display_name"    text        NOT NULL,
    "location"        text        NOT NULL,
    "city_id"         uuid        NOT NULL,
    "deleted_at"      timestamptz NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ("id"),
    CONSTRAINT "city_offices_fk"
        FOREIGN KEY ("city_id") REFERENCES "cities" ("id")
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "users" (
    "id"            uuid      NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
    "city_id"       uuid      NOT NULL,
    "office_id"     uuid      NOT NULL,
    "full_name"     text      NOT NULL,
    "phone_number"  text      NOT NULL,
    "primary_email" text      NOT NULL,
    "skype_id"      text      NOT NULL,
    "position"      text      NOT NULL,
    "created_at"    timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
    "updated_at"    timestamp NULL     DEFAULT NOW(),

    PRIMARY KEY ("id"),
    CONSTRAINT "users_city_fk"
        FOREIGN KEY ("city_id") REFERENCES "cities" ("id")
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT "users_offices_fk"
        FOREIGN KEY ("office_id") REFERENCES "offices" ("id")
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "cities" (
    "id"         uuid        NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
    "name"       text        NOT NULL,
    "deleted_at" timestamptz NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS "city_name_idx" ON "cities" ("name") WHERE "deleted_at" IS NULL;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "staff" (
    "email"     text NOT NULL,
    "skype_id"  text NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    "en_name"   text NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    "fa_name"   text NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    "type"      text NOT NULL,
    "office_id" uuid NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "offices_staff_fk"
        FOREIGN KEY ("office_id") REFERENCES "offices" ("id")
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE CASCADE
);

I have following go struct to load my information from database:
Info struct {
    UserID                  uuid.UUID   `gorm:"column:id"`
    Position                string      `gorm:"column:position"`
    City                    string      `gorm:"column:city"`
    Cellphone               string      `gorm:"column:cellphone"`
    Office                  Office      `gorm:"column:office"`
    Staff                   []Staff     `gorm:"column:staff"`
}

And this is how I query the database using gorm:
selectStatement := `select 
  u.id, u.position, u.phone_number as cellphone, 
  c.name as city, 
  f.* as office,
  s.* as staff
  from fellowship.users u 
  inner join cities c on u.city_id = c.id 
  inner join offices f on u.office_id = f.id 
  inner join staff s on u.office_id = s.office_id`

if err := db.Raw(statement).Scan(&users).Error; err != nil {
    return nil, err
}

I get this error:
invalid field found for struct Info's field Office: define a valid foreign key for relations or implement the Valuer/Scanner interface
I saw this post and tried this workaround:
Info struct {
    UserID                  uuid.UUID   `gorm:"column:id"`
    Position                string      `gorm:"column:position"`
    City                    string      `gorm:"column:city"`
    Cellphone               string      `gorm:"column:cellphone"`
    Office                  Office      `gorm:"column:office;foreignKey:office_id;references:id"`
    Staff                   []Staff     `gorm:"column:staff"`
}

if err := db.Raw(statement).Preload("office").Scan(&users).Error; err != nil {
    return nil, err
}

But I got the same error. Can anyone please help?
